# when i click on the tab application gets closed

Tags: android, xml

i have created an application with 3 tabs,1)post,2)listview,3)mapview.when i click on the any tab for the first time it shows the corresponding content.if i click on any tab second time ,like first i click listview then if i  click post and again if try to click listview application gets closed.if anyone knows it please kindly help me

The source code i have written is,

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;

public class TabWidgetActivity extends TabActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab
// Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
intent = new Intent().setClass(this, PostEvent.class);
// Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("post").setIndicator("Post",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_grey))
                  .setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);
// Do the same for the other tabs
intent = new Intent().setClass(this, EventList.class);
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("list").setIndicator("ListView",
res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_grey))
                  .setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);
intent = new Intent().setClass(this, MapViewEvents.class);
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("map").setIndicator("MapView",
               res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_grey))
                  .setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);
tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
}
}
```

Comment: paste the logcat error detail in the question

Answer (score 0):

Now try again.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;

public class TabWidgetActivity extends TabActivity {

TabHost tabHost;
TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost

Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab
// Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
intent = new Intent().setClass(this, PostEvent.class);
// Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("post").setIndicator("Post",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_grey))
                  .setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);
// Do the same for the other tabs
intent = new Intent().setClass(this, EventList.class);
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("list").setIndicator("ListView",
res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_grey))
                  .setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);
intent = new Intent().setClass(this, MapViewEvents.class);
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("map").setIndicator("MapView",
               res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_grey))
                  .setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);
tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
}
}
```

Comment: You should atleast explain the actual problem, possible solution. If you make some changes in the code, tell user where you have made changes.